# JSON printing format

Tags: json, printing

I'm working with the type

```
data J = JObj[(String, J)]
     | JArr[J]
     | JStr String
```

When given the input :

```
JObj[("problem", "solving")]
```

I would like the output to be:

```
{"problem":"solving"}
```

But since JStr is a list, it keeps printing out `{["problem", "solving"]}`
which is the way JStr was specified up above, but not what I want.

Here is what I have:

```
  show(JStr x) = show x
  show(JObj x) = "{" ++ show (foldl (x)) ++ "}"
  show(JArr x) = show x
```

I believe I can use map/ fold (is my implementation wrong?) on the list but I'm confused as to how to proceed further. 
I also thought of using intercalate & intersperse within Data.List to approach this. Thnks

Comment: So the question is about show "{a:b, c:d}"? You may mark answer as solution.

Answer (score 2):

Consider the syntax at hand. For any pair `(String, J)` inside of the `JObj` list we'd like to eventually see `(s, j)` become `"s": j`

```
jpair :: (String, J) -> String
jpair (s, j) = show s ++ " : " ++ show j
```

Now, if we have a list `[(String, J)]` then we can produce a list of `"s": j` string fragments, but we need to combine them by interspersing commas instead of abusing the Haskell list syntax which would include the `[` and `]` brackets.

This functionality is available in `Data.List.intersperse`

```
intersperse :: a -> [a] -> [a]
```

or, even better, in `Data.List.intercalate`

```
intercalate :: [a] -> [[a]] -> [a]
intercalate med = concat . intersperse med
```

and we can use `intercalate` to get what we want

```
instance Show J where
  show(JStr x) = show x
  show(JObj x) = "{" ++ intercalate "," (map jpair x) ++ "}"
  show(JArr x) = show x
```